# use autocomplete feature of mapbox in ios application

Tags: ios, mapbox

Can we use autocomplete feature of `Mapbox` into iOS application ? 
I'm looking for some kind of help for that.

I have already created a map view using `Mapbox`. But now I want to add a `textfield` onto it and when i look for a place, the `autocomplete` feature should populate some place names for me.

Comment: for objective C check this link https://github.com/tingslabs/TIMapboxGeocoder

Comment: did you find a solution ?!

Answer (score 1):

autocompletesQuery is enabled by default, you can change it with `options.autocompletesQuery = BOOL` then get the results array of suggestions like

```
let task = geocoder.geocode(options: options) { (placemarks,     attribution, error) in
            print(placemarks)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [MapboxGeocoder.swift](https://github.com/mapbox/MapboxGeocoder.swift) and [UISearchBar](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBar_Class/).